# Счет нечетных чисел

Tags: массивы, python-3.x

нужно подсчитать количество нечетных чисел в массиве.Делать за меня прогамму не надо.Только навести на мысль.

```
def createArray():
    import random
    lengthArray = int(input("Введите колво чисел от 0 до 50:"))
    array = []
    for i in range(lengthArray):
        array.append(random.randint(0, 50))

    return array
```

Comment: обходите массив, узнаете четность числа (получая остаток от деления на 2, т.е. `x%2`), считаете

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы найти сколько чисел нечётные в заданной коллекции:

```
odd_count = sum(1 for n in numbers if n & 1)
```

Comment: А может, проверка на равенство нулю остатка от деления на 2 будет яснее побитового сравнения с 1? Я понимаю, что это быстрее и кулхацкерски, но читаемость разве не важнее?

Comment: @gbg: я не думаю, что это быстрее.  Я пишу код, который считаю более читаемым (другие люди могут другой код более читаемым считать: у меня не всегда впереди сознания,  что `n % 2` положителен в Питоне. Нужно остановиться и задуматься, что `n % 2 == 1` работает.

Comment: А как вы бы сделали проверку на кратность, например, 19?

Comment: @gbg:  прочтите заголовок вопроса.

Comment: Я вижу заголовок вопроса, мне просто интересно для общего развития.

Comment: @gbg: отдельный вопрос тогда задайте, если не знаете

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75706/discussion-between-gbg-and-jfs).

Answer (score 0):

Создание и подсчет рандомного списка

```
import random
array = []
for i in range(100):
    b = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    if b % 2 == 1:
        array.append(b)
print(len(array))
# 56 в зависимости от рандома
```

Создание и подсчет чисел от 1 до 100

```
a = [i for i in range(100) if i % 2 == 1]
print(len(a), a)
# 50
```

Update

```
def count_array(count):
    a = [i for i in count if i % 2 == 1]
    return a


def create_array():
    import random
    length_array = int(input("Введите колво чисел от 0 до 50:"))
    array = []
    for i in range(length_array):
        array.append(random.randint(0, 50))

    return count_array(array)

print(len(create_array()))
```

Comment: мне нужно чтобы из определенного массива с случайными числами были подсчитаны все нечетные числа в этом массиве.массив-array

Comment: @Egor добавил рандом

Comment: спасибо)))))))))

Comment: я забыл сказать ,что я сделал рандомный генератор чисел в массиве.сейчас скинруdef createArray():
    import random
    lengthArray = int(input("Введите колво чисел от 0 до 50:"))
    array = []
    for i in range(lengthArray):
        array.append(random.randint(0, 50))
    print(array)
    return array

Comment: def createArray():
    import random
    lengthArray = int(input("Введите колво чисел от 0 до 50:"))
    array = []
    for i in range(lengthArray):
        array.append(random.randint(0, 50))
    print(array)
    return array

Comment: я должен добавить отдельную функцию ,которая все это определяет

Comment: я имею в виду нечетные числа

Comment: поможете?)Я скинул функцию

Comment: @Egor обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Возможный такой подяод:

1. Сделайте новый массив (список) только из нечетных чисел первоначального.
2. Используйте функцию `len()`.

Код может выглядать так:

```
new_list = [element for element in orig_list if element % 2 == 1]
necetnych = len(new_list)
```

Результат оперетор `%` (модуло) - это *остаток по делении первого оператора вторым*, и так когда остаток по делении *двумя* будет `1`, первый оператор должен быть 
нечетный.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы из определенного массива с случайными числами были подсчитаны все нечетные числа в этом массиве.массив-array

Comment: Код был правильным, только вместо *"нечетный"* я ошибочно применил атрибут *"отрицательный"*. Я поправил это в моем ответе и тоже добавил короткое объяснение.